# mantener las sesiones abiertas de dos proyectos de laravel alojadas en el mismo servidor xampp

Tags: laravel, session

Tengo dos proyectos laravel en un mismo servidor,

por ejemplo:

**aplicacion1.laravel.com**

**aplicacion2.laravel.com**

Utilizan bases de datos diferentes, pero sucede que al loguearse en una aplicación, cierra la sesión de la otra aplicación que esta en el mismo servidor.

Como pudiera solucionar este problema

Comment: fijate si el session domain está configurado diferente para cada subdominio, si ves algo del tipo `.laravel.com` eso incluye subdominios, segun la versión de laravel lo podes definir en .env  vars o en `config/session.php`

Comment: Encontre esto en los dos: 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null), 

el valor de null es el que debería cambiar para establecer el dominio independiente en cada uno ?

Comment: el null es el default si no encuentra el valor en el .env , asi que edita el .env y ponele un `SESSION_DOMAIN=xxx.dominio.com` diferente a cada proyecto, eso debería fijar las cookies y dominios de sesion correctamente, seguramente haya un php artisan para borrar caches o limpiar sesiones que haga funcionar la cosa

Comment: le asigne el dominio 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'sistema.domain.com'), y mi pagina automáticamente se seguía cerrando con me logueaba en la otra aplicación. El otro error que me salió es que daba error de pagina expirada y aunque intentaba autenticarme seguía saliendo pagina expirada

Comment: agregue en el .env    SESSION_DOMAIN=sistema.dominio.com y cuando intento autenticarme me regresa a la pagina de autenticación

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` creo q es la q refresca desde el lado del servidor, del lado del cliente hay q borrar las cookies ( aunque el logout debería borrarlas si mal no recuerdo ) en ambos subdominios ( sino uno va a pisar al otro )

Comment: sigue haciendo el mismo problema, me sigue sin permitirme entrar en la sesion